# curl cli post fails HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: curl, command-line-interface

I am trying to automate uploading new firmware to my company's customers routers using curl. I am trying to simulate the routers web user interface that does this function.
I have captured the http headers and they are as follows:

```
POST /Forms/upload_1 HTTP/1.1

Host    192.168.1.1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
DNT 1
Referer http://192.168.1.1/upload.html
Authorization   Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------24464570528145
Content-Length  1455180
```

---

looking at the form post data I see several hidden fields:
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tools_FW_UploadFile"; filename="v1.08"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

### Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UpgradeItemFlag"

My curl cli script gets a  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.
output:

```
C:\curl>curl -u "admin:admin" -H "Host:192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1" -H "Accept:text
/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5" -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate" -H "Accept-Charset:
 ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" -H "Referer:http://192.168.1.1/upload.html" -H "DNT:1" -H "Expect:" -F "tools_FW_uploadFile=" -F "file=@c:\curl\v1.08"
 -F "UpgradeItemFlag=1"  "http://192.168.1.1/Forms/upload_1" -v
* About to connect() to 192.168.1.1 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.1.1... connected
* Connected to 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /Forms/upload_1 HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
> Host:192.168.1.1
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
> Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
> Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5
> Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
> Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
> Referer:http://192.168.1.1/upload.html
> DNT:1
> Content-Length: 1422382
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------805f48e96301
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: RomPager/4.07 UPnP/1.0
< EXT:
<
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.1 left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

my curl is :

```
curl -u "admin:admin" -H "Host:192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1" -H 

"Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5" -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate" -H 

"Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" -H "Referer:http://192.168.1.1/upload.html" -H "DNT:1" -H "Expect:" -F "name=tools_FW_uploadFile" 

-F "file=@c:\curl\v1.08" -F "UpgradeItemFlag=1"  "http://192.168.1.1/Forms/upload_1"
```

If anyone can see what I'm doing wrong I would be very grateful.
the form has html as follows:

```
<INPUT TYPE="FILE" NAME="tools_FW_UploadFile" SIZE="30" MAXLENGTH="128"><INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="UpgradeItemFlag" VALUE="0">

<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" NAME="FW_apply" VALUE="Update Firmware" onClick="uiDoUpdate()"

function uiDoUpdate()
{

document.Firmware_Upload.UpgradeItemFlag.value=1;
document.Firmware_Upload.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same issue today and all of my Google Fu did not turn up the proper results. The specific issue for me when trying to work with `curl` was the line endings in the execution script. The fix for me was to actually run curl on a Linux system with Linux/Unix style line endings in the execution script. These are LF (\n) instead of CRLF (\r\n).

You can check a file with `file /path/to/script.sh`
If `file` mentions anything about line endings, your script is incorrect and must be converted.

You can convert a file with `dos2unix -U /path/to/script.sh`

I would highly recommend that you try the exact same curl command from an actual Linux system as curl on Windows is very finicky with form-data.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue today. @Myles Steinhauser's answer just saved my day.

Let me provide more details about it.

In my case, I use bash [r]ead to read line by line from file. Then it takes line as a value and assign it to the HTTP GET request variable, which looks like "http://example.com/uri?arg1=$line". When I execute the bash script, it return 400 Bad Request.

Solution: convert file's newline style from dos to unix

Explanation: Bash read use unix newline delimiter(\n), while the curl may takes a dos style(\r\n) file as an argument. That means, your curl phrase might be interpreted as curl "http://example.com/uri?arg1=abc\r". The trailing '\r' will lead to HTTP Bad Request.

Refer to https://ss64.com/bash/read.html to know more about bash read.

Ways to convert file type: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/